# Smart Table data binding

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm working on the UI and I have problems with data binding using a Smart Table.

I have 3 entities: A, B and C. B and C are navigation properties of A, all relations are 1 to 1. I want to show all properties of A, B, C in one Smart Table. I tried many methods and tried changing the **entitySet** and **tableBindingPath** parameters but I can display properites of one entity.

How can I show properties of all entities in one column?

Comment: Can you share a working example of what you tried so far? Maybe a link to some code on jsbin would be very good.

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming that you are using an odata service for this.

Have you setup associations(navigation) between your different entities in the service itself? You should then be able to use expand in your xml view or binding in the controller [like this](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/91/f11c116f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070/content.htm) and reference the seperate data properties.

Please check [this blog post](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3559486) to see a working example. Do note that it will probably run into cors issues.